# TableView ChangeListener Throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, changelistener

I'm making some kind of file system explorer, so to speak. I have a `TableView` with one `TableColumn` in it. `TableColum` is filled with names of the files in current folder. I want to be able to click on the one item in that `TableColumn` and, if that item is a folder, move to that folder. For that, I think, I need a `ChangeListener`. The problem is, it seems that it throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. I don't why it does that. I think I know where it happens, but I don't know why.

Here is the relevant code:

```
@FXML TableView fileSystem;
private File previous = null;
private File current = null;

private void listFiles() {
    try {    
        ObservableList<MyFile> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        if (current.listFiles() != null && list != null) {
            for (File i : current.listFiles()) {
                if ((i.isDirectory() || isPicture(i)) && !i.getName().equals("$Recycle.Bin"))
                        list.add(new MyFile(i));
            }
            fileSystem.setItems(list);
            path.setText(current.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // File System Change Listener
    fileSystem.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        ObservableList selectedCells = fileSystem.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();
        if (selectedCells != null && selectedCells.size() != 0) {
            TablePosition position = (TablePosition)selectedCells.get(0);
            if (position != null && fileSystem.getColumns() != null && fileSystem.getColumns().size() != 0) {
                int row = position.getRow();
                TableColumn tableColumn = (TableColumn)fileSystem.getColumns().get(0);
                try {
                    String fileName = (String)tableColumn.getCellData(row);

                    System.out.println(fileName);
                    String name = current.getAbsolutePath();
                    if (!name.endsWith("\\"))
                    name += "\\";
                    name += fileName;

                    File file = new File(name);
                    System.out.println("This: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
                    System.out.println("Current: " + current.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        previous = current;
                        current = file;
                        listFiles();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });


 }
```

And here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.subList(ReadOnlyUnbackedObservableList.java:136)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeListener$Change.getAddedSubList(ListChangeListener.java:242)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.handleSelectedCellsListChangeEvent(TableView.java:2959)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewArrayListSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:2395)
    at javafx.scene.control.TableView$TableViewSelectionModel.clearAndSelect(TableView.java:1898)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.simpleSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:215)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TableCellBehaviorBase.doSelect(TableCellBehaviorBase.java:148)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.CellBehaviorBase.mousePressed(CellBehaviorBase.java:150)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:95)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3758)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3486)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2495)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:350)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$350(GlassViewEventHandler.java:385)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$304/912389815.get(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:404)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:384)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:927)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.java:101)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/1963387170.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The problem seems to be in this line: `String fileName = (String)tableColumn.getCellData(row);`
References `current` and `previous` have been initialised, I already checked that.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: If you want, I can post the entire source code, but I thought it best to ommit te parts that are irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Do you have [cell selection enabled](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#setCellSelectionEnabled-boolean-) in your table's selection model? Or just the default row selection?

Comment: I didn't change it, which means it has to be the default, right? But, I added a `Button` and, in the event handler of that `Button`, I did the exact same thing as the above and it works. It opens a new folder when I select it in `TableView` and then press the `Button`.

Comment: If you are using row selection, I would not call `getSelectedCells()`, but `getSelectedItems()`. That gives you the row items as a list. So you can just get the one you are interested in and then directly get the property you need; no need to mess with going through the view to get the data. I suspect the selected `TablePosition` values are not properly initialized if you are using row selection.

Comment: Even though it did make my code shorter and easier to read, it didn't solve my problem. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: I can't really figure out what your code is doing. This exception is usually caused by changing the contents of an observable list while a change to that list is already being processed. Often this is a result of changing the contents of a table's items list in response to a change in its selected items. I can't see that your code explicitly does this, but it might.

Comment: @James_D - the call to `listFiles` in the end of the change listener changes the items property of the table view.

Comment: The listFiles changes the items. Can I solve this with this construct: `Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { listFiles(); } });`

EDIT: Yes, this solved my problem. Thanks a lot. :D